# Stuck on 16 - 17 level of Overthewire bandit game

Tags: linux, ssh, terminal, port, ctf

I'm playing the CTF game on Overthewire and stuck on 16 - 17 where you got a public key and have to submit it to play the next level.

I got the public key saved at /tmp/ and set read only for the user.Then proceed to submit it by this command

```
ssh -i /tmp/bokeh/sshkey17.private bandit17@bandit.labs.overthewire.org -p 2220
```

Then I got these messages

```
The authenticity of host '[bandit.labs.overthewire.org]:2220 
([127.0.0.1]:2220)' can't be established.
ED25519 key fingerprint is 
SHA256:C2ihUBV7ihnV1wUXRb4RrEcLfXC5CXlhmAAM/urerLY.                                          
This key is not known by any other names                                                                                
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes                                                
Could not create directory '/home/bandit16/.ssh' (Permission denied).                                                   
Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts 
(/home/bandit16/.ssh/known_hosts).   
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
This is an OverTheWire game server.                                                                           
More information on http://www.overthewire.org/wargames  
                                                                                                                                                                       
!!! You are trying to log into this SSH server with a password on port 
2220 from localhost.                             
!!! Connecting from localhost is blocked to conserve resources.                                                         
!!! Please log out and log in again.                                                                                                                                                                                                            
Load key "/tmp/bokeh/sshkey17.private": error in libcrypto                                                              
bandit17@bandit.labs.overthewire.org: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Please help me, thank you!

I think the error is at those permission denied that can not create the ssh folder

Comment: You have to connect from your machine, not from bandit16: "Connecting from localhost is blocked to conserve resources"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found something people use VMs, which have independent networks stuff from local environments. I can't explain clearly, since it might be different depending on the environments, **but if you use VMs, I think you can solve it** **:))**

You can do it in the bandit16's shell then it will work!

```
ssh -i key.rsa bandit17@localhost -p 2220
```

Before that, I used 'xshell' to connect to the bandit env in my local environment (my computer uses the school's private network...), and it didn't work. 'xshell' might have some connection limitations. But I tried to do it with a VM, and it works) (NOTE that I can't still specify the reason for it!)

Comment: Please don't answer blatantly off-topic questions - this has NOTHING to do with programming.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I examined the key closely and there was an odd character at the start of the key. I think using some of these text editors [I used Vim] a character gets inserted inadvertently. I edited the private.key file and removed the odd looking culprit and it worked after that.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so this code I'm going to provide will work regardless of whatever current level you're on, it will jump you directly to level bandit16 and the answer to the first flag:
echo 'JQttfApK4SeyHwDlI9SXGR50qclOAil1' | openssl s_client -ign_eof -connect localhost:31790
Alas, it isn't so easy this time though, copy the RSA from top to bottom Now we have an RSA key, what are we gonna do? Some said directly go to vim and I suppose that isn't wrong but due to permission issues you'll also need to make directories.
So this is how I did mine (named mine and, you can name it whatever):
mkdir /tmp/and && cd /tmp/and
Then do cd /temp/and
Then I did vim pea (again, can name it whatever). So, paste the RSA into vim, and then : and then x and then hit enter
Now if you run ls you should see pea listed.
From there you WILL NOT EXIT the level, stay logged in as bandit16 and paste the following snipet
ssh bandit17@localhost -p 2220 -i pea
Obviously if you named yours anything besides pea you'll have to change -i pea to whatever you named it.